# Tomcat server crashed while resizing a number of images

Tags: java, tomcat

I managed to bring down the server that was running my web app. It's a Tomcat 7 running a JVM with a pretty decent spec. One of my controllers is used for producing resized versions of images. I visited a page that was asking this controller for a number of resized images. The server died a terrible death with only this line in the catalina.out log. No traces of anything anywhere else (that i can find). I am puzzled. What happened to it? no google search results for this line.

```
java: cmsio0.c:1293: cmsSaveProfileToIOhandler: Assertion `(hProfile != ((void *)0))' failed.
```

The relevant code that does the resizing is here, as requested:

```
try {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    LOG.debug("Resizing image to thumbnail dimensions");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thumbnails.of(imageInputStream).size(maxSide, maxSide).outputQuality(0.5).outputFormat(JPG).toOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    LOG.debug("Completed in {} ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(imageInputStream);
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the code you use to resize the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be 100% certain, but it sounds very similar to a problem we had on our production server.

Basically an OOM error occurs, but the problem is that the heap allocation that the JVM was trying to make failed (in our case because we set our XMX to more then the physical memory without creating any swap space). Due to how *nix handles this situation it can just seemingly randomly kill the process. There is usually a log somewhere else in the system that tells you that it killed a process to free up memory. Our fix was the set the XMX to less than the physical memory because the core issue wasn't that we we're using too much actual memory, but that JVM was trying to allocate too much memory that wasn't backed up by physical memory, even though it wasn't strictly needed. Your image resizing sounds similar.

Comment: i could not have hoped for a better answer. this sounds just like what i could be experiencing. my friend set up a machine in a cloud and told me he gave it heaps of memory, but could be that the physical memory available is less than what he allowed the JVM. Will check with him on the actual physical server spec and will configure different xmx for the jvm. This probably is also the reason why I am not getting this running locally with 16GB RAM